# Having an issue serilazing DataTable given record with UTF-8 colulm

Tags: c#, .net, asmx

Is there any simple way to handle the serialization issue given the utf8 fields inside a record?

Also, I'm using the old ASMX Web API based on soap and I want to return a response as a JSON.

Here is the code sample suppose to handle the serialization. Note that I'm using `Newtonsoft.Json` Library

The issue that I'm getting gibberish fields

[image]

```
  public static DataTable GetVlue(string sprQuery,int Entry)
    {

        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["somecon"].ConnectionString))
        using (var command = new SqlCommand(sprQuery, conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@entry", Entry);
            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
            {
                da.Fill(table);

                return table;
            }
        }

    }
```

**  main function part**

```
 table = DbService.GetVlue(storedProcedurequery,Entry);

                    JSONString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(table);
                    Context.Response.Write(JSONString);
```

Answer (score 0):

So the way to solve the issue is by defining the response charset as `UTF`

I had to add the following section of code to solve the given issue `Context.Response.Charset = "utf-8"`